# Matchings in random bipartite graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of a text or paper which would help deal with the following problem

Suppose i am given a $K_{\mathrm{log}(n)} \times K_{\mathrm{log}(n)}$ bipartite graph in which edges occur randomly with probability $p(n)$, i want to find the size of the largest matching w.h.p for certain values of $p$.

Comment: Using $\log n$ instead of $n$ adds nothing to the problem except a change of notation. Define $N=\log n$ and consult the literature such as http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5535 .

Comment: Ok, i thought perhaps the fact that one tends to $\infinity$ may make a difference, thanks for the reference! Also in your problem the number of neighbors selected is a constant $d$ will that make much of a difference.